# What is the RESTful way of implementing a GET request that allows the filtering of potentially hundreds of resource Ids?

Tags: rest

Let's say I am developing a recipe API and it provides access to recipe resources consisting of the ingredients, instructions, and, of course, a lengthy back story of the recipe):

```
GET /recipes/   - returns a paginated list of recipes
```

Now, let's say that I've been asked to implement a feature where user's can request recipes that they have not tried yet.  One possible request for that could be:

```
GET /recipes?tried=false
```

Because the service that manages recipes is most likely different than the service that manages which recipes a user has seen, this route sounds like the wrong approach.

Perhaps an improvement would be:

```
GET /user/{user_id}/recipes?tried=false
```

This suggests that that user service could obtain a list of all the recipes the user has tried and then send a request to the recipes service to return a paginated list of recipes excluding those that the user has already tried.

But this means that there will be a route like such:

```
GET /recipes?exclude=202,203,420,109,...,400
```

and this could exceed the maximum length for URLs.

Is there a RESTful way to support these features without running the risk of URLs that are too long?

I thought of creating a new resource called a filter, that would allow the caller to create a filter with a POST that includes a list of recipe IDs that the user has tried, and passing the URL or ID of this filter to the recipes service, and then deleting the filter resource but that started sounding too complicated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I like your 2nd example best. Even if a "different service" is managing what is viewed, perhaps it makes the most sense for that service to store "tried" information in the recipe service. But alternatively, how about `GET /user/{user_id}/collections/tried`, where "tried" is the name of a collection?

Answer (score 1):

To me this sounds more like a question for the software engineering stack exchange, but I'll try to give an answer anyway.

In my opinion, there is no right or wrong way to do it, but you could get away like this: The user/fronted queries the recipe URL with an `unseen` request parameter. The service behind that retrieves a list of recipes the user has already seen from the service that has this piece of information.   Now you have two options: Fetch the list of all recipes and drop the seen ones manually, or have a POST endpoint on the recipe backend where the database can handle the job, taking a JSON/xml encoded list of the recipes to filter out.